# Get data from different LMS with tincan API

Tags: api, tin-can-api, canvas-lms, lrs

How can I get data from several LMS (Moodle, Blackboard etc) with Tincan API (LRS) ?

To be specific I want to get at least these infomation

Student info,
Teachers info,
Sessions info,
Classes info,
Courses info

I also need to know the implementation process and API endpoints to make request to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those specific pieces of information aren't necessarily available in any sort of direct way using the xAPI (Tin Can API). xAPI stores data points in a stream of statements, those statements *may* include some of that information depending on how and what generated them.

To access the statement stream you would need to make xAPI requests to the `/statements` resource provided by the LRS. You would have to ask the individual vendors for the location of their xAPI "endpoint" and for information on credentials for accessing that endpoint. Once you have that information I would suggest using one of the open source libraries linked at http://experienceapi.com/libraries to interface with the LRS. A lot of additional information about what xAPI provides, how to use it, etc. is available at that site.

Comment: Thanks. At least got a way to dive in.